# Text to date conversion in Access 2007 DB, .net 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I have few tables in which I'm storing dates in text format(dd-mm-yyyy). For some reason, I'm converting text date data into date format(dd-MM-yyyy) while copying these data to another table on a page load event. But if the date value is less than 13, it is swapping date and month values otherwise it works fine. Eg: 01-04-2014 becomes 04-01-2014 while 14-01-2014 remains same.Important thing is if I run same query from back end it copies data very well.
Please help I am looking for a quick fix.
TIA

Comment: Show the code which you are using to convert your date ? Otherwise how can we tell what is the issue ?

Comment: Actually it's a simple query like, insert into table2 select *  from table1 within OleDbDataAdapter object. Table2 has same fields as table1 but dates are in date/time format.